Pandas:using list as cell value - different approach to modify values and NaN issues
This is 50% a question and 50% an observation that baffles me a bit. Maybe someone can enlighten me.
Also I would like to know opinions on using lists as cell values. Yes/No and why please.
Here is a trivial example:
data = [[['apple', 'banana'],1], [['grape', 'orange'],2], [['banana', 'lemon'],4]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Fruit', 'Count'])

which results in:
             Fruit  Count
0  [apple, banana]      1
1  [grape, orange]      2
2  [banana, lemon]      4

Given a new list:
input_list = ['melon', 'kiwi']

The using 'loc' approach:
(A) Outright doesn't work.
df.loc[df['Count'] == 2, 'Fruit'] = [input_list] # with or without wrapping brackets is both bust

(B) Using Series also doesn't work
ser = pd.Series(input_list) # NO wrapping which is an incorrect length Series object - fair enough
df.loc[df['Count'] == 2, 'Fruit'] = ser

# wrong result --->

             Fruit  Count
0  [apple, banana]      1
1             kiwi      2
2  [banana, lemon]      4

(C) Series Take 2
ser = pd.Series([input_list])  # WITH wrapping = Series --> 0 [melon, kiwi]
df.loc[df['Count'] == 2, 'Fruit'] = ser

# wrong result ---> NaN??? HUH?

             Fruit  Count
0  [apple, banana]      1
1              NaN      2
2  [banana, lemon]      4


The using 'at' approach:
(D)
mask = df['Count'] == 2
mask_match_idx = df[mask].index.values[0] # first match int value
df.at[mask_match_idx, 'Fruit'] = input_list

# results in (finally) the correct result

             Fruit  Count
0  [apple, banana]      1
1    [melon, kiwi]      2
2  [banana, lemon]      4

I understand that B is bust because of the wrong length Series object.
But why are (A) (or a version thereof) and (C) wrong? Or how could they work? Especially the NaN result is confusing. Why is that happening?
Is the conclusion to always use 'at' in those kind of cases?
And again: What are the takes for using lists as cell values in regards to stuff like this happening etc. Would love some input here and potential alternative suggestions if lists are a no go.
Thank you!

Pandas is not designed to use lists as items. you should really avoid it.

Thanks @mozway. That's fair enough but what is the alternative if you need to use data structures of arbitrary length? I know I could expand the rows for every item in the list but I am trying to avoid that if possible as that would massively inflate the dataframe. Alternative would be using 2 or more DFs at once. That's almost like a DB then. Any more elegant solution to this?

You might want to try polars, which is (partially) designed to handle such nested structures.

Thanks for the feedback. I see what you mean. I found it here: https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/expressions/lists/
